# Sorting string arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

```
let names = ["Chris", "Alex", "Ewa", "Barry", "Daniella"]
func backwards(s1: String, s2: String) -> Bool {
    return s1 > s2
}
var reversed = names.sort(backwards)
print(reversed)
var ascending = names.sort({ (s1: String, s2: String) -> Bool in
    return s1 < s2
})
print(ascending)
let sortAscending = { (s1: String, s2: String) -> Bool in
    return s1 < s2
}
ascending = names.sort(sortAscending)
```

I am suppose to sort this code according to the number of characters they have from the most to the least. For example, Daniella has 8 characters so she will be fist in the list. The output I am suppose to get is 
`["Daniella", "Barry", "Chris", "Alex", "Ewa"]`

Comment: Hey man, you might also want to check our `sort` vs `sorted` discussion below — I don't think your code  compiles at all :(

Comment: i used  var sorted = ascending.sort { $0.characters.count > $1.characters.count }  and it works

Comment: You meant `sorted`, right?

Comment: when I used sorted I got an error but no errors for sort

Comment: @LeoDabus ...not okay: he is using `sort` and expecting a return value, makes no sense, even when in-place sorting *mutable* collections. BTW, does Swift returns an empty tuple (aka, `Void`) in such scenarios? That would explain why his code compiles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let names = ["Chris", "Alex", "Ewa", "Barry", "Daniella"]
let sortedNames = names.sorted { $0.characters.count > $1.characters.count }
print(sortedNames)
```

**Should I sort or should I sorted?** Use `sort` to order the original array in-place, if declared as a `var`; if `let` your code won't even compile. Use `sorted` to leave your original array alone and return a new, properly sorted array; works on `let` and `var`.

Comment: names is immutable. You need to use `sorted`method

Comment: I know :) Was thinking about a good name for the sorted array, but gave up haha...

Comment: He means that you need to call `names.sorted` instead of `names.sort`. I don't think your current code compiles.

Comment: My bad... it does now :)

Comment: He could use `sort` also but he would need to declare the array as variable

Comment: Resuming sort is a method on MutableCollection

Comment: ok thanks! to get my output i just have to replace names with ascending.